# How to describe spatial tranformations that contain singularities?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

I am a researcher in the field of medical image processing.  A popular topic in this field is the search for spatial transformations that align two images from two different patients in order to find anatomical correspondences between the two images.

As a constraint for the search of a suitable spatial transformation, it is often valid to consider only the space of homeomorphisms.  This means intuitively that it is sufficient to continuously deform one image so that similar anatomical structures in both images are mapped onto each other.  Mathematically, this problem is often written in terms of diffeomorphisms (and as a consequence, we are able to embed it in a Riemannian space, induce a metric, etc...)

In some cases however, the space of homeomorphisms/diffeomorphisms is not sufficient.  For instance, in the case where one image contains an object that is not present in the other image, it is desirable to shrink the object until it disappears.  Or vice versa, we want to make 'a hole' in the image without the object in order to map it on the image which contains the object.  As an analogy to diffeomorphisms, does there exist a theory that is able to describe such spatial tranformations (intuitively:  'diffeomorphisms with an occasional singularity')?

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: I don't know much about the theory but I have heard the term "almost diffeomorphism" used before to refer to homeomorphisms that are diffeomorphisms except at one single point.